# HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR and Reverse DNS Route 53

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53, amazon-lightsail

I have a little problem. I have an Istance on Lightsail with Plesk installed. When I sent an email, it going in the gmail spam folder. I use a lightsail istance with route53 DNS ZONE  and I have opened all the necessary ports. My domain is in Netsons ( I have already paste the amazon nameserver into netsons platform)

I tested the mail on Mail-Tester and the test tell me that i have  HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR problems.

I can't understand where is the problem because THE INCOMING EMAIL WORKS FINE. The outcoming go to the spam folder...Can you help me?

Answer (score 1):

In order to consistently send email from an amazon lightsail instance, you'll need to get a PTR record setup for your static IP. Amazon has a process for that.

Follow the instructions on https://lightsail.aws.amazon.com/ls/docs/en/articles/amazon-lightsail-configuring-reverse-dns to get that setup.

Even with PTR records setup, you should configure your mail server to sign outbound messages with DKIM and publish SPF records.

Once you've got that setup, it may still take a bit of time to establish a good reputation for your instances IP.

Answer (score 0):

I just spent hours looking working on very same problem and the anwser is dumb. Assuming you've got all the DKIM,SPF,reverse DNS stuff setup HELO_DYNAMIC_IPADDR will still bump up your score by 3.2 on spamcheck.postmarkapp.com

Solution when running Plesk on Lightsail appears to be from the Panel go Tools&Settings>General Settings>Server Settings>System Settings then Full Hostname. Out of the box it will be set to 'blahblahlah.amazonaws.com' change this to yourdomain.com.